# ¿Cómo calcular la rentabilidad de una ConfusionMatrix?

Tags: r

Si al generar la matriz de confusión me devuelve los siguientes resultados, quisiera saber como puedo calcular la rentabilidad del modelo sabiendo que por cada TP gano 1000 $ y por cada FP pierdo 250$:

[image: resultado]
<sub>(fuente: [subefotos.com](https://thumbs.subefotos.com/c26102ea1aae11db672a8d48f65b4801o.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Bienvenido Kelvinator a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.. Si bien en el caso de tu pregunta es simple de reproducir un ejemplo en R, te sugiero que no pegues imágenes en reemplazo de código/resultados u objetos, revisa como crear un [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que hay alguna forma de "monetizar" el modelo desde el paquete `caret`, lo que se me ocurre es una simple suma aritmética, la diagonal de la matriz de confusión seran nuestros aciertos, los errores se pueden expresar como la matriz menos los aciertos. Por ejemplo:

```
library(caret)

set.seed(2018)
cm <- confusionMatrix(iris$Species, sample(iris$Species))
cm$table

            Reference
Prediction   setosa versicolor virginica
  setosa         15         20        15
  versicolor     18         14        18
  virginica      17         16        17

sum(diag(cm$table) * 1000) - (sum(cm$table * 250) - sum(diag(cm$table) * 250))
[1] 20000
```

Nota:

- Mediante `cm$table` accedemos a la tabla correspondiente a la matriz de confusión
- `diag()` nos da la diagonal de la matriz

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Patricio, Un abrazo